# How to use C # to read large Excel

Tags: .net, c#

There are four xlsx files in total. The first column of each file has an ID, which can be 1 from the first line to 3000 and 2 from 3001-4930. It is similar to the one-to-many relationship of a database. The number of rows in each file exceeds 100w, so it can be divided into multiple xlsx. My current method is to use sqlbulkcopy to import them into SqlServer one by one and retrieve them according to their IDs, for example, the maximum value with ID equal to 1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: All programming questions are not within scope here at Super User. Unfortunately, this question wouldn’t be well received in it’s current form at Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please provide more details: What do you want to do with the data? Have you investigated/tried some things yet? If yes, provide the code. What’s this about SQL Server and how does it relate to your C# question? What .NET? Framework? 4.8? Once your question has all the details and fits Stack Overflow rules, it can be migrated.

Comment: `It is similar to the one-to-many relationship of a database.` not at all. Sheets have no relations. 4K rows isn't a lot either, an Excel sheet can have up to a million rows. There are a lot of libraries that can read Excel data and `SqlBulkCopy` isn't one of them. You must be using some other library and finally importing the data into the database

Comment: What's the question? If you use SqlBulkCopy you're already using C#, already loading the sheets. Importing the sheets into a database is a *good* solution, provided you clean it up, split it into separate tables if needed etc. You'll have to do the same thing even if you decide to load the data as DataTable rows or `List<T>`s. Using a database, provided you have clean data, makes querying a lot easier and faster